# During the over can captain change the bowler?

Tags: rules, cricket

In a cricket match can the captain of the fielding team change the bowler during the over, for any reason aside from  necessity (like injury)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. At the time of the question, this was covered by [Law 22.7(a)](https://web.archive.org/web/20170702061242/https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-22-the-over/):

> Other than at the end of an innings, a bowler shall finish an over in progress unless he is incapacitated or is suspended under any of the Laws.

With the 2017 rewrite of the Laws, this is covered by [Law 17.7.1](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws/the-over); the wording is essentially identical.